# How do i monitor when an specific ID appears on the screen with javascript mutations?

Tags: javascript

I am using a site that is kind of a slideshow but doesn't show the "next" link after a few seconds. I want to do a script that clicks on that link as soon as it appears.

I researched and found out "mutations" however i have little experience with javascript. Here's what i got so far. The link i want to click shows up in chrome as:

```
a href="#" class="btn btn-step-active" id="btn-next-step">Next
```

Code:

```
function clickButton() {
    document.getElementById('btn-next-step').click();
}

const app = document.querySelector('#btn-next-step');

const observer = new MutationObserver((mutations) => {
  mutations.forEach((mutation) => {
    if (mutation.addedNodes) {
      const nextStepAdded = [...mutation.addedNodes].some((node) => node.className === 'btn btn-step active');
      if (nextStepAdded) {
        clickButton();
      }
    }
  });
});

observer.observe(app, { childList: true, subtree: true });
```

However this doesn't seem to work, i get error "failed to execute observe on mutationobserver: parameter 1 is not of type node". any ideas?

EDIT: it appears the error is caused because the link doesn't exist... which is the whole purpose of what i am trying to do. but i put a parent id that is actually present when the page loads and now it worked!

Comment: that's because `app` is undefined at the time you're trying to observe it, it needs to be the parent of the next button and then in the MutationObserver callback you should look for `mutation.type == 'childList'` and find `#btn-next-step` trigger the click on it

Comment: thanks Amin, i actually caught it on my own, i put the parent node and it works now

Comment: Glad to hear you got it figured out but here's a fiddle I made just in case: https://jsfiddle.net/cxw9resp/

Answer (score 1):

The first parameter to `observer.observe` needs to be a node that is an ancestor of the node you are looking for not the node itself.

Something like:

`observer.observe(document.body, ....)`

Comment: thanks, that would have been an expensive solution, fortunately the next link had an immediate ancestor (a div that contained the link)